# Looping in Javascript Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Please help.

***Senario:***

I am doing a PHP project that reads the data in database and presents it using chart or graph.

***Problem:***

But the problem is, when I do the for loop in Javascript, it is not working. Help me.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    /* ChartJS
     * -------
     * Here we will create a few charts using ChartJS
     */
    //-------------
    //- PIE CHART -
    //-------------
    // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.

    var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);

    var PieData = [
       {
           <?php for($i=1;$i<$num_rows;$i++){  ?>

       {
            value: <?php echo $qtys[$i];?>,
            color: "#d2d6de",
            highlight: "#d2d6de",
            label: "<?php echo $items[$i];?>"
       }
       <?php } ?>
 ];
 pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
 });
</script>
```

This is my PHP file:

```
<?php
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo $num_rows;
    $items=array();
    $qtys=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result)) {

        $this->stock_id = $row["id_barang"];
        $this->type = $row["jenis_barang"];
        $items[]=$this->type;
        $this->quantity = $row["kuantiti"];
        $qtys[]=$this->quantity;
        $this->weight = $row["berat"];
        $this->category = $row["kategori"];
        $this->supplier_id = $row["id_pembekal"];
   }
?>
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <!-- DONUT CHART -->
          <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Donut Chart</h3>
              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
            <div class="chart">
                <canvas id="pieChart" style="height:250px"></canvas>
            </div>
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
          </div><!-- /.box -->
    </div>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow ;)

Comment: the graph is not shown. thanks @www139

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a syntax error:

```
    var PieData = [



      { // <------------------------------------------
<?php for($i=1;$i<$num_rows;$i++){  ?>

      {
        value: <?php echo $qtys[$i];?>,
        color: "#d2d6de",
        highlight: "#d2d6de",
        label: "<?php echo $items[$i];?>"
      }
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Leon said, you have this extra `{` before your php loop you need to remove but there's something else. You need to separate your items inside curly brackets with a comma. There are many ways to do that but the way I usually use is putting every item as a string inside an array then implode them. Here what I would do would be this :

```
<?php
$data = array();
for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++){ // (you need the element number 0 as well...)
$str = '
   {
    value: '.$qtys[$i].',
    color: "#d2d6de",
    highlight: "#d2d6de",
    label: "'.$items[$i].'"
  }';
$data[] = $str;
?>

var PieData = [
<?php
echo implode(",", $data);
?>
];
```

Comment: thanks for your help but after i do this code,the graph is not shown in my page.i code it all same like the code you have shown to me

Comment: Can you upload a ZIP of the files you are using or post a fiddle so I can try and see what's wrong ?